# How to show UiProgress Bar in Split mode iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to create Progress bar like Instagram ?

[image]

I am using Uiprogressbar but its not showing new value when i am setting to progress bar -

```
float duration = [[CameraManager.temporaryFileDuraions lastObject] floatValue];
self.videoRecrodingProgress.progress = self.videoRecrodingProgress.progress - duration;
```

Comment: have you found any solution? i want same progress bar as instagram. any help is appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the same reference of progress in split mode. It will work